# Remote Blob Storage with Content Organizer

Tags: content-organizer, rbs, remote-blob-storage, content-organizer-rule

I set up a 3th party RBS provider with SharePoint 2013 SP1.

The Sharepoint site works as follows:
- Users drop their files into a DropOff Library which is handled by a Content Organizer which moves the file, depending on specific criteria to a another folder.

As soon as we upload the file, I see it coming in to my RBS store (shredded into 65K files)

But because of the Content Organizer, the file is not accessible anymore as soon as it is located on the new library.

Is this a bug or a configuration error? And how to solve/bypass this?

Comment: Anyone that can help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this issue on my Test-environment.

While going into Acceptance, I didn't had this issue anymore.

RBS with Content Organizer so is Supported without any doubt.
My issue was environmental.

Probably failed to work in Test because of the following:
Tests were done on several Content Databases, and while using $rbss.Disable() (to disable the RBS feature, - DO NOT EVER USE THIS -) it makes your Content Database go corrupt and unusable for further RBS usage.

Answer (score 0):

I've set up SP farms with blob offload at storage level, and I'm pretty sure that Content Organized was used later in those farms without any problems. So I'd bet it's something with RBS provider you use.

What RBS provider are you using? Is it custom code or something like Metalogix's?

Comment: Aziz, I'm using EMC SourceOne for Microsoft SharePoint - Storage Management as 3th party Provider.